# How should I connect to a VC in Discord?

Tags: python, python-3.x, chatbot, discord.py

I'm trying to make a music bot for Discord. The only part that I'm having trouble on is making the bot actually play the music.

---

I'm running my bot on a Macbook with PyCharm. I haven't tried that much only because I have no clue what to do. You can see the code I used:

````py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

import asyncio
import itertools
import sys
import traceback
from async_timeout import timeout
from functools import partial
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL


ytdlopts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'outtmpl': 'downloads/%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s',
    'restrictfilenames': True,
    'noplaylist': True,
    'nocheckcertificate': True,
    'ignoreerrors': False,
    'logtostderr': False,
    'quiet': True,
    'no_warnings': True,
    'default_search': 'auto',
    'source_address': '0.0.0.0'
}

ffmpegopts = {
    'before_options': '-nostdin',
    'options': '-vn'
}

ytdl = YoutubeDL(ytdlopts)


class VoiceConnectionError(commands.CommandError):
    pass

class InvalidVoiceChannel(VoiceConnectionError):
    pass

class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):

    def __init__(self, source, *, data, requester):
        super().__init__(source)
        self.requester = requester

        self.title = data.get('title')
        self.web_url = data.get('webpage_url')

    def __getitem__(self, item: str):
        return self.__getattribute__(item)

    @classmethod
    async def create_source(cls, ctx, search: str, *, loop, download=False):
        loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()

        to_run = partial(ytdl.extract_info, url=search, download=download)
        data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, to_run)

        if 'entries' in data:
            data = data['entries'][0]

        await ctx.send(f'```ini\n[Added {data["title"]} to the Queue.]\n```', delete_after=15)

        if download:
            source = ytdl.prepare_filename(data)
        else:
            return {'webpage_url': data['webpage_url'], 'requester': ctx.author, 'title': data['title']}

        return cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source), data=data, requester=ctx.author)

    @classmethod
    async def regather_stream(cls, data, *, loop):
        loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
        requester = data['requester']

        to_run = partial(ytdl.extract_info, url=data['webpage_url'], download=False)
        data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, to_run)

        return cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(data['url']), data=data, requester=requester)


class MusicPlayer:
    __slots__ = ('bot', '_guild', '_channel', '_cog', 'queue', 'next', 'current', 'np', 'volume')

    def __init__(self, ctx):
        self.bot = ctx.bot
        self._guild = ctx.guild
        self._channel = ctx.channel
        self._cog = ctx.cog

        self.queue = asyncio.Queue()
        self.next = asyncio.Event()

        self.np = None
        self.volume = .5
        self.current = None

        ctx.bot.loop.create_task(self.player_loop())

    async def player_loop(self):
        await self.bot.wait_until_ready()

        while not self.bot.is_closed():
            self.next.clear()

            try:
                async with timeout(300):
                    source = await self.queue.get()
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                return self.destroy(self._guild)

            if not isinstance(source, YTDLSource):
                try:
                    source = await YTDLSource.regather_stream(source, loop=self.bot.loop)
                except Exception as e:
                    await self._channel.send(f'There was an error processing your song.\n'
                                             f'```css\n[{e}]\n```')
                    continue

            source.volume = self.volume
            self.current = source

            self._guild.voice_client.play(source, after=lambda _: self.bot.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(self.next.set))
            self.np = await self._channel.send(f'**Now Playing:** `{source.title}` requested by '
                                               f'`{source.requester}`')
            await self.next.wait()

            source.cleanup()
            self.current = None

            try:
                await self.np.delete()
            except discord.HTTPException:
                pass

    def destroy(self, guild):
        return self.bot.loop.create_task(self._cog.cleanup(guild))


class Music(commands.Cog):
    __slots__ = ('bot', 'players')

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.players = {}
        if not discord.opus.is_loaded():
            discord.opus.load_opus('opus')

    async def cleanup(self, guild):
        try:
            await guild.voice_client.disconnect()
        except AttributeError:
            pass

        try:
            del self.players[guild.id]
        except KeyError:
            pass

    async def __local_check(self, ctx):
        if not ctx.guild:
            raise commands.NoPrivateMessage
        return True

    async def __error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.NoPrivateMessage):
            try:
                return await ctx.send('This command can not be used in Private Messages.')
            except discord.HTTPException:
                pass
        elif isinstance(error, InvalidVoiceChannel):
            await ctx.send('Error connecting to Voice Channel. '
                           'Please make sure you are in a valid channel or provide me with one')

        print('Ignoring exception in command {}:'.format(ctx.command), file=sys.stderr)
        traceback.print_exception(type(error), error, error.__traceback__, file=sys.stderr)

    def get_player(self, ctx):
        try:
            player = self.players[ctx.guild.id]
        except KeyError:
            player = MusicPlayer(ctx)
            self.players[ctx.guild.id] = player

        return player

    @commands.command(name='connect', aliases=['join'])
    async def connect_(self, ctx, *, channel: discord.VoiceChannel=None):
        if not channel:
            try:
                channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
            except AttributeError:
                raise InvalidVoiceChannel('No channel to join. Please either specify a valid channel or join one.')

        vc = ctx.voice_client

        if vc:
            if vc.channel.id == channel.id:
                return
            try:
                await vc.move_to(channel)
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                raise VoiceConnectionError(f'Moving to channel: <{channel}> timed out.')
        else:
            try:
                await channel.connect()
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                raise VoiceConnectionError(f'Connecting to channel: <{channel}> timed out.')

        await ctx.send(f'Connected to: **{channel}**', delete_after=20)

    @commands.command(name='play', aliases=['sing'])
    async def play_(self, ctx, *, search: str):
        await ctx.trigger_typing()

        vc = ctx.voice_client

        if not vc:
            await ctx.invoke(self.connect_)

        player = self.get_player(ctx)

        source = await YTDLSource.create_source(ctx, search, loop=self.bot.loop, download=False)

        await player.queue.put(source)

    @commands.command(name='pause')
    async def pause_(self, ctx):
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        if not vc or not vc.is_playing():
            return await ctx.send('I am not currently playing anything!', delete_after=20)
        elif vc.is_paused():
            return

        vc.pause()
        await ctx.send(f'**`{ctx.author}`**: Paused the song!')

    @commands.command(name='resume')
    async def resume_(self, ctx):
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        if not vc or not vc.is_connected():
            return await ctx.send('I am not currently playing anything!', delete_after=20)
        elif not vc.is_paused():
            return

        vc.resume()
        await ctx.send(f'**`{ctx.author}`**: Resumed the song!')

    @commands.command(name='skip')
    async def skip_(self, ctx):
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        if not vc or not vc.is_connected():
            return await ctx.send('I am not currently playing anything!', delete_after=20)

        if vc.is_paused():
            pass
        elif not vc.is_playing():
            return

        vc.stop()
        await ctx.send(f'**`{ctx.author}`**: Skipped the song!')

    @commands.command(name='queue', aliases=['q', 'playlist'])
    async def queue_info(self, ctx):
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        if not vc or not vc.is_connected():
            return await ctx.send('I am not currently connected to voice!', delete_after=20)

        player = self.get_player(ctx)
        if player.queue.empty():
            return await ctx.send('There are currently no more queued songs.')

        upcoming = list(itertools.islice(player.queue._queue, 0, 5))

        fmt = '\n'.join(f'**`{_["title"]}`**' for _ in upcoming)
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f'Upcoming - Next {len(upcoming)}', description=fmt)

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    @commands.command(name='now_playing', aliases=['np', 'current', 'currentsong', 'playing'])
    async def now_playing_(self, ctx):
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        if not vc or not vc.is_connected():
            return await ctx.send('I am not currently connected to voice!', delete_after=20)

        player = self.get_player(ctx)
        if not player.current:
            return await ctx.send('I am not currently playing anything!')

        try:
            await player.np.delete()
        except discord.HTTPException:
            pass

        player.np = await ctx.send(f'**Now Playing:** `{vc.source.title}` '
                                   f'requested by `{vc.source.requester}`')

    @commands.command(name='volume', aliases=['vol'])
    async def change_volume(self, ctx, *, vol: float):
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        if not vc or not vc.is_connected():
            return await ctx.send('I am not currently connected to voice!', delete_after=20)

        if not 0 < vol < 101:
            return await ctx.send('Please enter a value between 1 and 100.')

        player = self.get_player(ctx)

        if vc.source:
            vc.source.volume = vol / 100

        player.volume = vol / 100
        await ctx.send(f'**`{ctx.author}`**: Set the volume to **{vol}%**')

    @commands.command(name='stop')
    async def stop_(self, ctx):
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        if not vc or not vc.is_connected():
            return await ctx.send('I am not currently playing anything!', delete_after=20)

        await self.cleanup(ctx.guild)


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Music(bot))
````

> Mostly from [here](https://gist.github.com/EvieePy/ab667b74e9758433b3eb806c53a19f34).

---

This was my original code:

```py
if vc:
  if vc.channel.id == channel.id:
    return
  await vc.move_to(channel)
else:
  await channel.connect()

await ctx.send(f'Connected to: **{channel}**')
```

I used this code to try to debug the issue:

```py
vc = ctx.voice_client

if vc:
  if vc.channel.id == channel.id:
    return
  await vc.move_to(channel)
else:
  await channel.connect()
  while not ctx.voice_client:
    await channel.connect()
await ctx.send(f'Connected to: **{channel}**')
```

---

I expected the bot to join the channel and then "connect" to it, thus enabling it to play music through it. However, with my initial code, it gave an error `discord.errors.ClientException: Not connected to voice.` when I tried to play music through it. However, it sent the message through the chat. With my second iteration of the code, the message was never sent, leading me to believe that the bot never really connected to the channel.

[Image since I don't have enough reputation](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/381965515721146390/642039415169875987/Screen_Shot_2019-11-07_at_11.04.30.jpg)

As you could see, the bot appears in the voice channel, but isn't actually "connected."

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the 'play' command or the 'connect' command?

Looking over that, the 'connect' command will just connect to the voice channel but the play command will connect to the voice channel if it is not connected and then attempt to play the music.

I see that it is also using **discord.FFmpegPCMAudio**
This is directly from the discord.py documentation.

> **Warning:** You must have the ffmpeg or avconv executable in your path
>   environment variable in order for this to work.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=ffmpeg#discord.FFmpegPCMAudio

There is most likely an issue with your bot connecting to that channel. I just tested that code and got it to work fine. The fact that the message was never displayed when you used the second bit of code would tell me that the bot got stuck in the while loop because it couldn't connect.

You should try making a public voice channel and trying it with that or making sure your bot has sufficient permissions for the private voice channel you're using.

You could also try this to help you find out why it isn't working:

```
        try:
            voice_client = await channel.connect()
            # Code below this e.g.
            if not voice_client.is_connected():
                print(f"Not connected to {channel.name}")
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            raise VoiceConnectionError(f'Connecting to channel: <{channel}> timed out.')
        except discord.ClientException:
            print("You are already connected to a voice channel.")
        except discord.opus.OpusNotLoaded:
            print("The opus library has not been loaded.")
        except discord.DiscordException as ex:
            print(ex)
```

`connect()` 
Raises 3 exceptions and also returns a voiceclient, I have also included the base discord Exception to help find out what the issue is. See links below for the documentation.

Here is also a warning from the discord.VoiceClient documentation.

> **Warning:** In order to use PCM based AudioSources, you must have the opus library installed on your system and loaded through opus.load_opus(). Otherwise, your AudioSources must be opus encoded (e.g. using FFmpegOpusAudio) or the library will not be able to transmit audio.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=connect#discord.VoiceChannel.connect
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=connect#discord.VoiceClient

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the info at the top of the file where you got the code from, or just copy and paste it?

> "Please understand Music bots are complex, and that even this basic example can be daunting to a beginner.
>   For this reason it's highly advised you familiarize yourself with discord.py, python and asyncio, BEFORE
>   you attempt to write a music bot.
>   This example makes use of: Python 3.6
>   For a more basic voice example please read:
>       https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/rewrite/examples/basic_voice.py
>   This is a very basic playlist example, which allows per guild playback of unique queues.
>   The commands implement very basic logic for basic usage. But allow for expansion. It would be advisable to implement
>   your own permissions and usage logic for commands.
>   e.g You might like to implement a vote before skipping the song or only allow admins to stop the player.
>   Music bots require lots of work, and tuning. Goodluck.
>   If you find any bugs feel free to ping me on discord. @Eviee#0666"

https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py#installing

Or the installation information for discord.py?

> Installing Python 3.5.3 or higher is required
>
> **To install the library without full voice support**, you can just run
>   the following command:
>
> Linux/OS X python3 -m pip install -U discord.py
>
> Windows
>
> py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py
>
> **Otherwise to get voice support** you should run the following command:
>
> Linux/OS X python3 -m pip install -U discord.py[voice]
>
> Windows py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py[voice]

Answer (score 1):

these are the leave and join :

```py
@client.command()
async def join(ctx):

    if not ctx.message.author.voice:
        await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel!")
        return
    else:
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        user = ctx.message.author.mention
        await ctx.send(f'{user}, Connected to {channel}')
        await ctx.message.add_reaction('✅')
    await channel.connect()

@client.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    voice_client = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
    user = ctx.message.author.mention
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    if not voice_client:
        await ctx.send(f"{user} I am not connected to a voice channel")
    else:
        await voice_client.disconnect()
        await ctx.send(f'{user}, Disconnected from {channel}')
        await ctx.message.add_reaction('✅')
```

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine. The library installed just wasn't the voice version. It works fine with the voice version of the library.

Answer (score 0):

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['j', 'joi'])
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    else:
        voice = await channel.connect()

    await voice.disconnect()

    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    else:
        voice = await channel.connect()
        print(f"The bot has connected to {channel}\n")

    await ctx.send(f"Joined {channel}")
```